# Whats the underlying difference between receiving the chrome 404 page and the IIS 404 page?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, iis, http-status-code-404

As the title states, what is the difference between the two error pages. Specifically in terms of troubleshooting/debugging and what causes one page to be shown rather than the other.

[image: IIS 404 page]

[image: Chrome 404 page]

Comment: How did you generate the 2nd?  The first one is from IIS and is served from "CustomErrorModule" and is its Detail Error Page.   I'm guessing you got the 2nd from a server that either has CustomErrorModule uninstalled or disabled.   Furthermore, i'm guessing the 2nd is from a system that just returns a 404 with no 'body' in the response.

Comment: A browser itself can decide what kind of page to display, so the second one is from Chrome itself. To view the actual error page sent by IIS, analyze the actual web response, https://support.google.com/chrome/forum/AAAAP1KN0B0rGWIJ_UPF3M/?hl=en&msgid=xcNmkqWtAQAJ&gpf=d/msg/chrome/rGWIJ_UPF3M/xcNmkqWtAQAJ